# how to view hidden text using TR command in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I have a full hidden text named `ghost.txt`
when I

```
cat ghost.txt
```

I see just a lot of space with no characters.

How can i display the text?

Comment: `tr` is the wrong tool for the job. `hexdump -C` will show the actual content, you could also do `cat -A`.

Comment: A plain text file is just a set of bytes interpreted with a given character encoding. It's not possible to have "hidden text". Maybe you have spaces or [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Comment: @PabloBianchi it's a homework for school, and i am supposed to know the hidden code using the tr command ..

Comment: @JenaAlissa Have you tried `cat -A ghost.txt` like I suggested ? or `hexdump -C ghost.txt`. The `tr` command can replace characters, but we need to know the contents first and what type of characters to delete. That's what `cat` and `hexdump` can do for you.    It's possible the file either overwrites contents with `\r` or with control characters, but we need to know which one it actually is

Answer (score 1):

The homework requires you to transform the space and tabulation characters into something visible. For that, you can use the command `cat ghost.txt | tr [:blank:] [@]` to turn every space character into `@`. After that, the tabulation characters will appear as opening brackets "[", which will then reveal a hidden ASCII message. You can use then `grep --color` command to highlight the message.

<sub>The French version of this answer is available in the revision history</sub>

Comment: @user883198 Merci beaucoup! Thank you so much.. I am so lost, this homework doesnt make any sense. It's a joke. Do you wanna exchange emails or something so we could help each other a bit? I think i'd need more help than you do lol.